# Global matching in regex in variable

Tags: regex, perl

I have a perl script that contains a few regexes in variables, such as this:

```
my $velar_velar = qr/([a-zA-Z']*(?:[^n\s]g|[^n\s]k))\s+((?:g|k|c[^ieyh])[a-zA-Z']*)/;
```

Later, I use these in an `if` (and `elsif`) statements, but I want this regex to be able to match more than once per line:

```
$text = "tack go pack go";
   if ($text =~ /$velar_velar/g) {
   print "Yes";
   }
```

Where it would print "Yes" twice. I have tried the code I have here but it doesn't seem to work. I've also tried putting `/g` at the end of the regex variable but that does not work either.
How do I get my regex to match more than once when it is a variable? I

Comment: It is matching more than once.  But you have it in the scalar context under the `if` so all that `if` gets is the _number of matches_, it evaluates that to 'true' and it prints.  How would it print twice, it is evaluated just once.  Feed the regex output into an array, and you'll have all matches in it, etc.  Does this help?

Comment: The regex does return the list of all its matches -- when invoked in "list context." When in "scalar context" -- which is what you have under your `if` -- it returns the number of matches.  So if you have, say, 5 matches, your code becomes `if(5)`.  True, print.  Also, at any rate, that `if` is executed once and it cannot magically print more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `if ($text =~ /$velar_velar/g) {` to `while ($text =~ /$velar_velar/g) {`.